# Banco de dados para Currículos

Tags: php, mysql, mvc, padrão-dao

Boa tarde,

Estou fazendo meu projeto para TCC de um sistema de RH, só que tenho uma duvida enquanto a armazenar currículos. Na qual vai ter um formulário onde o usuário cadastra suas informações, e caso queira adicionar mais um curso ele clica no botão e  cria mais uma row na tabela. como a maioria dos sites.
Atualmente estou fazendo ela assim:

[image: tabela currículo com chave estrangeira ao usuário]

---

Com três tabelas usando chaves estrangeiras referenciando o currículo ao usuário. Mas vejo que dessa forma quando eu fazer o DTO e DAO, não vai dar certo. Poderiam me dar um norte de como fazer e boas práticas de fazer isto.

Obrigado.

Comment: Por que não vai dar certo? Parece-me ok um currículo estar associado ao usuário.

Comment: Então no caso só usaria o curriculoDTO herdando os outros três? Assim somente utilizaria um crud no curriculoDAO juntamente com funções para adicionar rows na tabela?